# Collapsing a 3 tier subquery to a Join statement

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I seem to be having an issue collapsing my 3 tier subquery to a join statement. 
Heres the code :

```
Select pid
from orders
where aid in (
    select aid
    from orders
    WHERE cid IN (
        select cid
        from customers
        where city = 'Kyoto'
                 )
             );
```

[The Database im currently working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slu1U.png)

EDIT: I am trying to show   the ids of  products    ordered through any agent   who makes   at  least   one order   for a   customer    in  Kyoto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select o.pid 
from orders o 
inner join orders oo on oo.aid = o.aid
inner join customers c on c.cid = oo.cid and c.city = 'Kyoto'
```

I think that the aliases (**o**, **oo** and **c**) are necessary to make it work as expected

Answer (score 1):

Why are you selecting from orders table multiple time and also I think your Agents and Products tables have no use here.

```
SELECT orders.pid 
FROM ORDERS orders 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS customers ON customers.cid = orders.cid 
AND customers.city = 'Kyoto'
```

Comment: aid refers to the agents so somehow it's relevant but not sure why

Comment: but if it is retrieved from orders table then no need of Agents.

Comment: But that still make no sense. You are getting aid from Orders table. You don't need to retrieve it from Agents table as per your requirement.

Comment: I'm not touching the agents table in this query

Comment: Yes that is why I am telling this and you don't need to self join with orders table. Check my query and it will provide you same result. Optimized with one less join.

Comment: the query you proposed only returns pids p01, p07, and p01 again. Where as p01, p07, p03, p04, and p05 are expected.

Comment: Will it?  If i understand the edit properly he wants ALL products ordered through an agent who has ANY orders for a customer in kyoto - you're only returning orders for customers in kyoto - but if an agent has produtcts to another city - it won't pull up

Comment: @MaggeWorld, but in that case we have to join with agents table and thats different requirement. I am talking about the query Brad put in question. To replicate that self join won't be required.

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.pid 
from orders as A
    INNER jOIN
Orders as B
on A.aid=B.aid
    INNER JOIN 
customers as C
on B.cid=C.cid
where C.city = 'Kyoto'
```